# Swarmplot rotate x-axis

Tags: python, seaborn

I like to rotate the x-axis of my swarmplot, but `ax.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right")` and `ax.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)` do not work. How do I do that? Thx.

```
random = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
name = ['name','longer_name','longest_name']
df2= pd.DataFrame(random, columns=name)


ax = sns.swarmplot(data=df2)
ax.set_xlabel('Words')
ax.set_ylabel('value')
ax.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody stumbles upon this question, my solution is the following:

```
ax = sns.swarmplot(data=df2)
ax.set_xlabel('Words')
ax.set_ylabel('value')
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=30, ha="right")
plt.show()
```